# rosdep update error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried `rosdep update` I get this:

```
$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro: invalid repo spec in gbpdistro data: You must update to a newer rosdep version by calling..sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep (make sure to uninstall the pip version on Ubuntu)
updated cache in /home/wagnelib/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

so, I have followed the advice removed the pip version of rosdep and:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
 ...
python-rosdep is already the newest version.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47177/rosdep-update-error/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me this works. Maybe just try running it again?

Other than that check what `which rosdep`, `rosdep --version` and `apt-cache policy rosdep` give you. I have 0.10.7.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-11-01**:
Tried again and the result is same.

```
$ which rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep
$ rosdep --version
0.9.5
```

...

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-11-01**:
$ apt-cache policy python-rosdep
python-rosdep:
Installed: 0.10.7-1
Candidate: 0.10.7-1
Version table:
*** 0.10.7-1 0
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-11-01**:
Finally, I have removed the python-rosdep package and again installed in and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem today which I manged to resolve and I think this is the best place to give the reasons and solution.

Firstly, when we try:

```
rosdep update
```

We get the following message, as OP mentions:

```
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro: invalid repo spec in bpdistro data: You must update to a newer rosdep version by calling..sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep (make sure to uninstall the pip version on Ubuntu)
updated cache in /home/wagnelib/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

The solution mentioned in this error message is incomplete (or let's say ambiguous). To me it seems like, "remove pip" and install the python-rosdep. Doing this leads to the following (this is what OP got):

```
$ which rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep
$ rosdep --version
0.9.5
$ apt-cache policy python-rosdep
python-rosdep:
Installed: 0.10.11-1
Candidate: 0.10.11-1
Version table:
*** 0.10.11-1 0
    500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As can be seen, rosdep version is 0.9.5, whereas the apt-cache policy is for rosdep version 0.10.7-1.
That is, although we installed the latest version using apt-get, the detected version is still the old one. What is the cause? The cause is, previous rosdep could only be installed/uninstalled using pip. So, we will have to uninstall the older rosdep using pip (which means, when the original solution said "uninstall the pip version", what was really meant was "uninstall older rosdep using pip"). This is how it would look:

```
$sudo pip uninstall rosdep
```

Now we can remove "pip" if we like, and we reinstall the newer version of rosdep:

```
$sudo apt-get remove --purge python-rosdep python-pip
```

Next, follow the regular steps:

```
$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
$which rosdep
 /usr/bin/rosdep
$rosdep --version
  0.10.11
$apt-cache policy python-rosdep
  python-rosdep:
  Installed: 0.10.11-1
  Candidate: 0.10.11-1
  Version table:
   *** 0.10.11-1 0
    500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

All the versions match now:). Remove the old sources file and perform rosdep init and update :

```
$sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
$sudo rosdep init
$rosdep update
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
  Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml
  updated cache in /home/race/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

And there it is, rosdep is ready for use. I hope this is useful.

---

Originally posted by [bakhol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2684/bakhol/) with karma: 196 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5373/shehzi/) on 2013-07-11**:
Worked like a charm even now. Thank you!

**Comment by [Xure](https://answers.ros.org/users/14191/xure/) on 2014-04-01**:
Hi, I'm quite new to ROS, I have a problem while updating rosdep, please help me ,thanks a lot !

xu@xu-lap:~$ which rosdep
/usr/local/bin/rosdep
xu@xu-lap:~$ rosdep --version
0.10.25
xu@xu-lap:~$ apt-cache policy python-rosdep
python-rosdep:
  已安装：  0.10.25-1
  候选软件包：0.10.25-1
  版本列表：
 *** 0.10.25-1 0
    500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xu@xu-lap:~$ sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
[sudo] password for xu:
xu@xu-lap:~$ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run

```
rosdep update
```

xu@xu-lap:~$ ^C
xu@xu-lap:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
The read operation timed out
xu@xu-lap:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosd